# Is it true that $xy\geq x+y$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I just see the [GM-AM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). But I would like to compare $xy$ with $x+y$ for any $(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

It looks like $xy>x+y$ since the first one is multiplication and the second one is addition.

Can we prove this? For $(x, y)\in\mathbb{N}^2$, can we prove it now?

Comment: What happens if $y=0$?

Comment: what happens if $x,y \in \mathbb N^2, x=1$ ? what if $x,y \in \mathbb R_+^2, x,y < 1$ ?

Comment: This is very off-topic but could anyone post a link to where I can read about what the indexes on top of the $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb N$ mean?

Comment: @mathh $\mathbb{R}^k$ refers to the set of $k$-tuples whose elements are in $\mathbb{R}$, similar for $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @mathh In general $S^k$ where $S$ is a set and $k\in\mathbb N$ denotes
$$S^k := \underbrace{S\times \ldots \times S}_{k\text{ times}} = \{(a_1, \ldots, a_k) | a_i \in S, 1\le i\le k \}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have $xy \geq x+y \iff (x-1)(y-1) \geq 1$.

Answer (score 4):

This only holds for a certain subset of $\mathbb R^2$. To find it, solve the equation $xy=x+y$, since this will be the border between $S_1:=\{xy < x+y\}$ and $S_2:=\{xy > x+y\}$.
Your equation is valid only on $\overline{S_2}$
Let us now find $S_2$:
$$xy = x + y \Rightarrow_{x\ne 0} y = 1 + \frac yx \Rightarrow y(1-\frac1x) = 1 \Rightarrow y = \frac1{1-\frac1x}$$
(Fun fact: $y$ is the Hölder conjugate of $x$)
Now for $x=0$ we have $y=0$ implied. $S_2$ is now given by $y > \frac1{1-\frac1x}$ if $x$ is positive and $y < \frac1{1-\frac1x}$ if $x$ is negative. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy+%3E+x%2By) for an image of $S_2$
[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, the first example gives the answer: with $x=y=1$ you have $xy=1$ and $x+y=2$. Same if $x=1$ or $y=1$, or if $(x,y)=(2,2)$. But in the other cases where $(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}^2$ it works, since $xy-(x+y)=(x-1)(y-1)-1> 0$.

Comment: Take $x = y = \frac12$... You should be careful with the formulation "other cases".

Comment: I looked that the question with $(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}^2$.

Comment: I cross-checked and there is still $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$. the restriction to $\mathbb N^2$ is a second question.

Comment: Yes indeed. At least this is an answer in this case.

Answer (score 3):

$$xy\geq x+y
\Rightarrow xy-x-y\geq 0
\Rightarrow xy-x-y+1\geq 1~~ \text{(adding 1 to both sides)}
\Rightarrow x (y-1)-(y-1)\geq 1
\Rightarrow (y-1)(x-1)\geq 1$$

Comment: Why was this post downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

For natural numbers it is true if both $x$ and $y$ are at least $2$ or greater and one of them is $3$ or greater. In general it's false.